# Necessary and sufficient condition for a linear operator to be invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, direct-sum

I need to prove the following proposition:

Let $V$ be a finite dimentional vector space and $T \in End(V)$ a non-zero linear operator, then $T$ is invertible iff for all $U$ and $W$ subspaces of $V$ it is the case that $V=U \oplus W \implies T(V)=T(U)\oplus T(W)$

I have already proved that if $T$ is invertible then given any two subspaces $U$ and $W$ s.t $V=U \oplus W$ it is the case that $T(V)=T(U)\oplus T(W)$ but I'm stuck with the converse. If I'm not wrong it should be enough to prove that $T$ is injective or surjective (no need to prove both) since domain and codomain have the same dimention, so my intention was to prove injectivity by taking some vector $v \in Ker(T)$ and concluding that $v=0$ but i couldn't get to that result. Any suggestions on how to prove surjectivity will also be welcome. Thanks

Comment: This isn't true... at least $T=0$ satisfies the latter property, but is not invertible. Maybe it's true as long as $T$ is not the zero operator?

Comment: Yes. Here's a hint: Assume $T \neq 0$ is not invertible. Let $v \in \ker(T)$ and $w \notin \ker(T)$. Extend $v, w$ to a basis of $V$, say $\{v, w, u_1, \ldots, u_k\}$. Then observe that $\{v+w, w, u_1, \ldots, u_k\}$ is also a basis of $V$, and use this to build a direct sum decomposition of $V$.

Comment: You are right, I forgot to mention that T is non zero